# Terinary operator to add user symbol

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, orgchart

how can add `<i class="fa fa-users symbol"></i>` on manager box to show user symbol icon in `Maansger2`nodes
below is the picture

[image]

tying this line where checking `${data.tcount}>0` but it shows in string

```
${data.tcount}>0?<div class="title">${data.title}<i class="fa fa-users symbol"></i></div>:<div class="title">${data.title</div>
```

data bind node template where need to add terinary operator

```
var nodeTemplate = function(data) {
                    return `
            
                   <div class="title">${data.title}</div>
                   <div class="content">${data.name} </br>${data.MainRole}</br>${data.Country} </div>
            
         
          
           `;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like this?

`<div className="title">{data.title} {data.tcount > 0 && <i className="fa fa-users symbol"></i>}</div>`